# Should we test for called functions signatures (including number of passed arguments)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

As far as I understand TDD, we should write minimum amount of tests to fail meeting our code's goal and then write only the code necessary to pass such tests.

However, does testing for called functions signatures, including testing for number of passed non-keyworded and keyworded arguments (like Python's `*args` and `**kwargs`), should be incorporated into our test suite as well?

For instance, if we have a function calling external API that may take numerous arguments with many defaults, I guess it makes sense whether we test we call such API precisely as intended (including passing no more arguments than necessary or checking we pass none of keyworded flags, as we do not need anything else than the default options)?

Answer (score 2):

> we should write minimum amount of tests to fail meeting our code's goal and then write only the code necessary to pass such tests

That correct but with one important addition: you need to do it on *each iteration* of TDD. So the end result (after many iterations) does not necessarily be small and simple. You create large things with small steps.

In the case you describe the essence of you function is to call external API with correct parameters depending on the input parameters. If you create it using TDD the test would be to provide some parameters to you function and check that the external API was invoked.

You would start creation your function with something simple and then make it more complex. Let's imagine you are calling external API that handle payments in you online storage application.

You can start from something like:

```
def test_payment():
    order_processor.external_api = Mock()

    order = Order(items=Item(quantity=10, price=10))
    order_processor.process(order)

    assert_that(order_processor.external_api.process_payment, called_with(amount=100))
```

Then you implement `OrderProcessor.process` passing only `amount` to `process_payment.

Next iteration of TDD would be to add buyer information:

```
def test_payment():
    order_processor.external_api = Mock()

    order = Order(
        items=Item(quantity=10, price=10),
        buyer=Buyer(id=567)
    )
    order_processor.process(order)

    assert_that(
      order_processor.external_api.process_payment,
      called_with(amount=100, payer=buyer.id))
```

Then you modify `process` to pass `buyer` information.